# Is "<li>" different from "<a>" on hover in terms of accessiblity?

Tags: html, css, hover, accessibility, html-lists

In optimizing accessibility for a website, I noticed the `<li>` is the hover state, not the `<a>`.

Is this a cause for concern?

I'm assuming it is better on the `<a>` as this is the target. However, W3 doesn't mention this at all.

[W3 — Fly-out Menus tutorial](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/) suggests it is the `<ul>` that holds the hover state, and I think it would make sense from a design perspective (padding etc).

Comment: a person who needs assistive technology does not hover with a mouse pointer. Accessibility wise it makes no difference. The question is not accessibility wise but UI/UX wise. What do you want to highlight when hovering? Do you want to highlight the list item or specifically a link?

Comment: @tacoshy - Be careful about making sweeping statements about those who use and benefit from AT, Disability includes a spectrum of different issues. For example, a user might use a screen reader because they are dyslexic. Such a person might well hover over an element using a mouse pointer.

Comment: @tacoshy I don't want to do anything. It's already performing in the 90s and mobile first. It's just a clarification and 100% an accessibility question. This is a huge corporate entity that knows their stuff and I'm perfecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that the list's hover state is "just" a visual cue, rather than actual content, and you should be fine either way.

Also, make sure that the hyperlink itself is well-formed - in particular check that it is keyboard operable - i.e. it should gain/lose focus with TAB, and support activation ("clicking") with ENTER. Make sure it has a meaningful accessible name (usually the link text, but often implemented as an image alt). These are much more important for accessibility than the hover effect.

If it's the list or the list item that get focus, and/or respond to clicking or keyboard input, then that's against the ARIA and HTML-AAM specs. (Lists and list items should be non-operable). By all means put a hover effect on what wraps the hyperlink if you need to, but the actual clicking/activation belongs on the hyperlink itself.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out, constructive answer @brennanyoung. Everything else is spot on including aria roles, labels, keyboard functionality, etc. It's already at 94% in Lighthouse, is mobile first - and exceptionally well performing overall. My task is to get as close to perfection as I can get - this was a question on refinement - so this helps a lot.

Comment: @JohnLewis Having the hover state be on the `<li>` can also cause issues if it's possible to hover over the list item without also hovering over the link—i.e., if the `<a>` element doesn't wholly cover the `<li>`. If that's the case you might cause confusion for sighted, pointer-wielding users who could think their pointer is over a link (because the hover state is triggered) but nothing is happening when they click.